# how can I find the average in array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, math

I am trying to create a function that will return the average of scores but am stuck in between the for loop process, if someone can please help me understand what I am missing it would help a lot

```
function getAverageTestScore(scores) {
  for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
   return scores[i]
  }
}

const avg = getAverageTestScore([80, 100]);
console.log(avg, '<-- should be 90');
```

Comment: Do you know how to find an average among a list of numbers?  Like, if you had to do it with pen and paper, how would you do it?  The answer to that is the start of your algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment a variable with the value of `scores[i]` return that variable divided by `scores.length`. Do not `return` from `for` loop

```
function getAverageTestScore(scores) {
  let n = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
   n += scores[i];
  }
  return n / scores.length
}

const avg = getAverageTestScore([80, 100]);
console.log(avg, '<-- should be 90');
```

Comment: Thank you! At lease you were nice enough to help me! I will thumbs this up when I get to!

Answer (score 0):

A popular and recommended way to treat these cases is using the method [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), for example look at the following example

```js
const scores = [10, 20, 30, 50, 10];
const average = scores.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index, array) => {
  accumulator += currentValue;

  if (index === array.length - 1) {
      return accumulator / array.length;
  }

  return accumulator;
}, 0);

console.log(average);
```

Before going to MDN give a read to this publication in it the author shares in a practical way other common scenarios where using reduces makes sense.

Basically the rule of thumb could be: When an array needs to be converted to a compact or summarized version of it, using reduce is a likely way to do it